# how to engage or target a specific item in the ListView to do some action with it only

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know how to target a specific item in a listView to perform some action with it only,

I've created a listView.builder that read from the database and display the data like posts, I've specified each item in the listView when get tapped, it will expand to display all its content, but when I tap on one of them, the tapping applies to all and all item gets expanded upon tapping.

how to fix this?

Comment: have you try using conditions? Like `if($index == 1){lines of code};`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with keys:
if you need more specific targeting just get the id of the listView item and add his id to the key, and then you have a unique target possibility.

See more here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: I specified the key of each item to ValueKey(index), then what to do after? @key